# sqlalchemy, use a callable in pre-defined query filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a lot of entities that I would like to filter in the same way, and several similar criterias. I would like to prepare these criterias and then just apply them when I need it.

I could write something like:

```
filter = Entity.owner==some_user
```

and then query:

```
query = session.query(Entity).... #some more 
query = query.filter(filter)
```

That's OK when `some_user` is predifined. Now I need to pass a callable there, so it will be evaluated at actual query build time: say, replace `some_user` variable with a result of `get_current_user()` call.

You may notice that these tree ways will not go:

```
filter = Entity.owner==get_current_user
filter = Entity.owner==get_current_user()
filter = Entity.owner==lambda: get_current_user()
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK to evalute them *just before* you build the query - which should serve the purpose of storing them just fine - you could store them in callable:

```
filter = lambda: Entity.owner == get_current_user()

query = session.query(Entity).... #some more 
query = query.filter(filter())
```

You can store expressions of any complexity this way. Use regular functions for more verbose cases.

Comment: It seems trivial and will mostly fit my needs :) I should try it.

Comment: I've decided to move some logic to hybrid attributes, but anyway, thank you for your help - it will be usefull in both cases!